# VLookup getting information from different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

As I step through my code I do not get any error however the code does not return anything. I do not know what to do in order to fix the issue.

Value of H5 = 161-0123. the first three numbers identify the type of part (Also which sheet I will be looking through) and the last four are the part number inside the specific sheet

```
Dim LookUp As String
Dim Typ As String

Typ = Left(Range("H5"), 3)
LookUp = Right(Range("H5"), 4)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wbk1 = Workbooks.Open("R:\Item Master List\Item Master Log.xlsx")

Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Set sheet1 = wbk1.Worksheets("161-Polyimide")

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I5").Value = Application.VLookup(LookUp, sheet1.Range("A:J"), 8, 0)
```

161-0123 has a component number associated with it which is what cell I5 is supposed to retrieve (195-1234)

Input in H5 = 161-0123

Output in I5 = 195-1234

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` anywhere?

Comment: No I do not. @BigBen

Comment: You may need to explicitly state which workbook `Worksheets("Sheet1")` is in

Answer (score 0):

Through tinkering I have figured out my problem and it was two part.

Firstly, this is a guess because I did this on the off chance of it working.

The cell H5 was formatted as General so when the "-" was added to the number it made the whole cell be considered as a string and the numbers in the other file are classified as numbers.

Secondly:

I had to specify `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I5").Value =` (thank you @cybernetic.nomad).

Comment: Also if this is some macro you run al the time, look into [`ExecuteExcel4Macro`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.executeexcel4macro) to prevent opening/closing of other workbooks

Answer (score -1):

Though the exact problem can be known, If I get the complete code but with the information you gave, In my experience, I have noticed that Excel behaves in a non-deterministic way mostly under 2 circumstances:

1. Excel may have entered into a Manual Sheet Calculation mode, either because you did so deliberately or if there are a lot of formulas on the sheet. You can verify this if you have the **Calculate** option in the bottom left of excel window.

[image]

2. You might have the Record Macro Option turned on.